# How to test web app in google workspace marketplace sdk before store listing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I wanted to create one web app for Gmail that scan mail for malicious URL and attachment and display it on the Web console.
So I have created one app that requires domain-wide admin installation in Google Workspace Marketplace sdk. But to publish it requires a Universal navigation URL to the web app. However, I have not found any way to test it and complete the web app. Without testing how can I show web app functionality?
So, How do I add a Universal navigation URL?